# Missing text beside relative time for Migrated questions?

Tags: feature-request

Seems there's a missing text beside the relative time for migrated questions at [Top Questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) page.

If anyone does any changes to the post it appears like "modified 5 mins ago".
If someone answers to a post it appears "answered 5 mins ago"

The following is the screenshot for the migrated question.

[image]

Is that by design? or kind of bug? It should be something like follows ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, since it is already reported the question has been migrated in the question page, I would expect the _Top Questions_ page show _migrated_; after all, the system knows it was migrated.

Comment: we don't record a "migrated" activity type on posts, the best we could do here atm, would be to show "modified" instead of nothing. This feature was originally requested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145039/can-we-add-asked-answered-edited-text-to-each-question-featured-on-the-f).